# get parent and childs from hierarchcial taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy and I want to show only children from 1 parent.

For example, the taxonomy looks like this:

```
- Events
-- Location
-- Date
- Region
-- State
-- StateCode
```

When I use my code, I get all child values...

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if ($term->parent != 0) { // avoid parent categories
        $options[] = array('label' => $term->name, 'value' => $term->term_id, 'id' => $term->term_id);
    }
}
```

Is it possible, that I can modify this lines to get only the children from Events for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

[`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function takes `$args` as first param. And you can use the same args as with [`WP_Term_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/).

Two arguments that may interest you are:

- `child_of` - (int) Term ID to retrieve child terms of. If multiple taxonomies are passed, $child_of is ignored. Default 0.
- `parent` - (int|string) Parent term ID to retrieve direct-child terms of.

So if you want to get only the terms that are children of Event term, then you can use this code:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'child_of' => <EVENTS_TERM_ID>,  // <-- you have to replace this with the term id of Events term.
) );
```

This way you don't need any `if`s in printing code any more.

Comment: i found a solution with get_term_children() but your solution is much more beautiful - Thanks!!!

Comment: `get_terms_children()` is using `get_terms()` to get these terms, so you'll end up using `get_terms` either way ;)